# How to iterate over "some" dimensions of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, functional-programming

I've got a three-dimensional numpy array of shape (2,2,2). I would like to think of it as a two-dimensional matrix with 1-dimensional arrays as entries.

What I would like to do is applying a function to each entry (i.e. each 1-d array) in my matrix. I know that I could vectorize my function to apply it to each number in my array. I also know that I can apply a function along one axis. However, I haven't managed to apply the functions along two axes.

Here's my latest trial:

```
import numpy as np

def sqrtSum(a, b):
    return np.sqrt(a+b)

def sqrtSumWrapper(row):
    return np.array([sqrtSum(x[0], x[1]) for x in row])

z = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
np.apply_along_axis(sqrtSumWrapper, 1, z)
```

In the example above, my desired outcome would be an array of shape (2,2) with the entries ((sqrt(3), sqrt(7)),(sqrt(11), sqrt(15)). When I run the code above I get a *invalid index to scalar variable.* error.

I think I'm missing an important aspect of how *apply_along_axis* works and would be thankful for your input how to correct the code.

EDIT:
The answers so far are focussing on changing the input function *sqrtSum*. This function is just an example. I'm interested in a general answer for an arbitrary input function that takes n input parameters and returns a scalar.

**Solution**:
The solution is amazingly simple (shame on me that I haven't seen it)

```
import numpy as np
def sqrtSum(a, b):
    return np.sqrt(a+b)

def sqrtSumWrapper(x):
    return sqrtSum(x[0], x[1])

z = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
np.apply_along_axis(sqrtSumWrapper, 2, z)
```

Thanks to all repliers.

Comment: Beware that `apply_along_axis` still iterates (at Python level) over the other dimensions.  It doesn't speed things up.  Look at it's code, or search SO for other questions about the function for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to use [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) correctly. The function to apply must be a function of a 1D array:

```
def sqrtSum(arr):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(arr))
```

```
>>> z = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
>>> np.apply_along_axis(sqrtSum, 2, z)
array([[1.73205081, 2.64575131],
       [3.31662479, 3.87298335]])
```

For comparison:

```
>>> np.array([[np.sqrt(3), np.sqrt(7)],[np.sqrt(11), np.sqrt(15)]])
array([[1.73205081, 2.64575131],
       [3.31662479, 3.87298335]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I haven't expressed myself clearly enough. The function sqrtSum is just a simple example. In practice, it might be much more complex (and maybe even unknown to me). So, how to answer my question if you consider the details of sqrtSum to be a black box?

Comment: `sqrtSum` can be any function that reduces a 1D array to a scalar. Which dimension, it depends on the axis argument passed to `apply_along_axis`. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy's sum and sqrt functions.

```
z = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
s = np.sum(z,axis = 2)
print s.tolist()
# [[3, 7], [11, 15]]
sqrt = np.sqrt(s)
```

Comment: Thanks. The functions is just an example. How about a general answer for an arbitrary function taking a 1-d array and returning a scalar?